# How to convert nested list into nested dictionary in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

This is my nested  list I want to convert this list into below nested dictionary
json_data =

```
[[[[[[[[[[[['{{app.elastic.hostname}}'], 'hostname:'],
          [['{{app.elastic.scheduleDuration}}'], 'scheduleDuration:'],
          [['{{app.elastic.dataDuration}}'], 'dataDuration:'],
          [['{{app.elastic.displaySummary}}'], 'displaySummary:'],
          [['{{app.elastic.recordSize}}'], 'recordSize:']]]],
       'elastic:']]]],
   'app:'],
  [[[[[[[[[['{{spring.profiles.active}}'], 'active:']]]], 'profiles:'],
      [[[[[['{{spring.redis.host}}'], 'host:'],
          [[[[[['{{spring.redis.sentinel.master}}'], 'master:'],
              [['{{spring.redis.sentinel.nodes}}'], 'nodes:']]]],
           'sentinel:'],
          [['{{spring.redis.password}}'], 'password:'],
          [['{{spring.redis.port}}'], 'port:']]]],
       'redis:']]]],
   'spring:']]]
```

and I want to expect below on structure

```
list_dic = {
    "app": {
      "elastic": {
        "hostname": "{{app.elastic.hostname}}",
        "scheduleDuration": "{{app.elastic.scheduleDuration}}",
        "dataDuration": "{{app.elastic.dataDuration}}",
        "displaySummary": "{{app.elastic.displaySummary}}",
        "recordSize": "{{app.elastic.recordSize}}"
      }
    },
    "spring": {
      "profiles": {
        "active": "{{spring.profiles.active}}"
      },
      "redis": {
        "host": "{{spring.redis.host}}",
        "sentinel": {
          "master": "{{spring.redis.sentinel.master}}",
          "nodes": "{{spring.redis.sentinel.nodes}}"
        },
        "password": "{{spring.redis.password}}",
        "port": "{{spring.redis.port}}"
      }
    }
  },
```

The above nested dictiionary is my expected result.
The is my python recursive function to get above nested dictionary

```
def gen_final_json(list_obj):
list_dic = {} 
for i in list_obj:
    if isinstance(i, list):
       list_dic.update(gen_final_json(i))
    else:
        list_dic[i]={}
return list_dic

final_dict = gen_final_json(json_data)
print(final_dict)
```

The above code produce wrong result I need above nested result.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the minimal efforts on how you would progress on coding the question above.

Comment: def gen_final_json(list_obj):
    list_dic = {} 
    for i in list_obj:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            for j in i:
                if isinstance(j, list):
                    v = gen_final_json(j)
                v = j
        else:
            list_dic[i] = i+1
    return list_dic

Comment: Please add the above sample code comment to your question. More information can be found here on [how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Hi Roxy, I added my sample code here.